# Is there a way to show two images simultaneously with a JavaScript image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I'm trying to create a comic book reader using JavaScript where the content of the gallery is dynamically generated from the images in a given directory (directory is chosen with a bit of PHP). I want to display two pages (images) at a time so the comic is read like it would be in a book format. Users are then able to navigate two pages at a time with their arrow keys.

So far I can only get one page to load and view at any given time.

How can I do this? I don't want to have to hard-code every gallery.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you gave us what you have so far.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could generate a directory listing with PHP and put it into the javascript on the page?